# Magento 2 Order Confirmation Email Send Programatically from Success.php

Tags: magento-2.1, order-email, order-confirmation

I have disabled Order Confirmation Email from backend because I want to send Order Email when User redirect to Success.phtml after order successfully placed.

I have created Plugins for it
`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="<vendor_name>\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success"/>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender">
        <plugin name="sale_order_custom_email_send" type="<vendor_name>\Checkout\Model\Plugin\Sender" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender">
        <plugin name="sale_order_sender_custom_email" type="<vendor_name>\Checkout\Model\Plugin\OrderSender" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Created Around Plugin: `OrderSender.php`

```
<?php

namespace <vendor_name>\Checkout\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderSender
{
    /**
     * Order success action.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function aroundSend(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $subject, \Closure $proceed, Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false, $isCustom = false)
    {
       $order->setSendEmail(true);
        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
            if ($this->checkAndSend($order, $isCustom)) {
                $order->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        }

        $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'send_email');

        return false;
   }
}
```

I have passed `$isCustom` parameter in `checkAndSend()` method so It can check my custom condition.

Second Plugin : `Sender.php`

```
<?php

namespace <vendor_name>\Checkout\Model\Plugin;

class Sender
{
    /**
     * Order success action.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    protected function aroundCheckAndSend(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender $subject, \Closure $proceed, Order $order, $isCustom = false)
    {
       $this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());
        if (!$this->identityContainer->isEnabled() && $isCustom = false) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->prepareTemplate($order);

        /** @var SenderBuilder $sender */
        $sender = $this->getSender();

        try {
            $sender->send();
            $sender->sendCopyTo();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }

        return true;
   }
}
```

If `$isCustom` is `true` then even if Order Confirmation is Disabled from backend It should send Order Confirmation Email to customer.

Don't Know where am I wrong but not getting any email. May be We can not create a plugin for Absract class's Protected method but any other solution to change condition in `checkAndSend()`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you cant make plugin for protected method, you have to try another way.

Comment: Use this free extension https://magecomp.com/magento-2-order-confirmation-email.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you specified in your question that you have disabled Order Confirmation email from backend, I have assumed the same and write code in such a way that email will not sent twice even if you have enabled Order Confirmation email from backend. So, Order Confirmation Email will only sent from success page when you have disabled it from backend.

To send email on order success page, we need to bind observer with event ***checkout_onepage_controller_success_action***. Here, We write our code send mail. To assure that email is not sent twice, I have created plugin for **isEnable()** method of **OrderIdentity.php** class from **Magento_Sales** module.

First, you need to register event using events.xml. Check the below code.

**[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\etc\frontend\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_sendmail" instance="[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Observer\SendMailOnOrderSuccess" />
    </event>
</config>
```

After registering event, We will create Observer Class.

**[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Observer\SendMailOnOrderSuccess.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SendMailOnOrderSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
     */
    protected $orderModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
     */
    protected $orderSender;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderModel
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderModel,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->orderModel = $orderModel;
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        if(count($orderIds))
        {
            $this->checkoutSession->setForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess(true);
            $order = $this->orderModel->create()->load($orderIds[0]);
            $this->orderSender->send($order, true);
        }
    }
}
```

After adding observer, order cofirmation email will sent on order success page, if we have enabled order confirmation email from **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales Email > Order.** But, now order confirmation sent twice if we enable this field. So, we need to create plugin to avoid this scenario.

To create plugin, you need to use **di.xml**.

**[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity">
        <plugin name="change_is_enable_method" type="\[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Plugin\Sales\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentityPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Plugin\Sales\Order\Order\Email\Container\
OrderIdentityPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Plugin\Sales\Order\Email\Container;

class OrderIdentityPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @return bool
     */
    public function aroundIsEnabled(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        $returnValue = $proceed();

        $forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess = $this->checkoutSession->getForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess();
        if(isset($forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess) && $forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess)
        {
            if($returnValue)
                $returnValue = false;
            else
                $returnValue = true;

            $this->checkoutSession->unsForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess();
        }

        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellence Answer.

Comment: when i am put di.xml in frontend it's not working. i need to disable order confirmation email only for frontend.

Comment: Event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action ` Only works if Emails communication in ON. It did not trigger if Emails communication is OFF Magento2.2.2.

Comment: in this case, send an email is not working from admin. please comment about it.