# Duplicate order confirmation mail

Tags: magento2, orders, email, duplicate

Thanks for providing solution. I have apply same solution in one of my site along with I have follow all your steps. But it still send two confirmation mailto both admin and customers. My magento version is: 2.2.5.

Please provide me solution on this. Let me know if you need to ask anything.

Thanks,
Sheba Maniar

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248603/duplicate-order-confirmation-emails-when-checking-out-with-paypal-express?rq=1