# Magento 2 email_order_set_template_vars_before observer triggers only when I resend email in the admin

Tags: magento2, event-observer, template, custom-variable

I created a new template var using `email_order_set_template_vars_before` observer and it works when I send email new order through the Magento admin. But it does not trigger when new order is placed. Here is my code.

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <!-- <observer name="shipperhq_save_email_variables" disabled="true"/> -->
        <observer name="cd_shipperhq_save_email_variables" instance="Foobar\ShipperHQDeliveryDate\Observer\SaveEmailVariables"/>
    </event>

</config>
```

**SaveEmailVariables.php**

````
namespace Foobar\ShipperHQDeliveryDate\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveEmailVariables implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $carrierGroupHelper;
    public function __construct(\ShipperHQ\Shipper\Helper\CarrierGroup $carrierGroupHelper) {
        $this->carrierGroupHelper = $carrierGroupHelper;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
        $order = $transport->getOrder();
        $orderDetail = $this->carrierGroupHelper->getOrderCarrierGroupInfo($order->getId());

        if($order != null)
        {
            foreach ($orderDetail as $orderData) {
                $ddate = array_key_exists('delivery_date', $orderData) ? $orderData['delivery_date'] : '';

                $transport['cddeliveryDate'] = date( 'F d, Y', strtotime( $ddate ) );

            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182051/magento-2-order-confirmation-email-send-programatically-from-success-php

Comment: Is that events.xml file under "app/code/Foobar/ShipperHQDeliveryDate/etc/adminhtml/"?

Comment: I have a question about your order emails. What is your value on `sales_email/general/async_sending`? Are emails being sent on submit or being triggered later on?

Comment: please create event.xml  in global. it's maybe due to a scope issue.

Answer (score 1):

The described behaviour point to wrong placed the events.xml file in the directory hierarchy. If you want to catch dispatched event globally (in frontend and admin) you need to declare `events.xml` file under `[module_name]/etc` directory. In your case it'll be:

```
app/code/Foobar/ShipperHQDeliveryDate/etc/events.xml
```